# Spring Security Basic auth returns 404 after successful login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

**SCENARIO:**

I have two spring services sharing the session via redis. One service is my auth service, the other one the ui. Now I want to authenticate against the auth service, get a session an a status code 200 back if login was successfull (WITHOUT FORM LOGIN). I got the mechanism going an I can authenticate successfully.

**PROBLEM:**

Even if I am successfully authorized i get status 404 back.

**WHAT I EXPECT:**
My goal is that a client can call the auth service and gets a valid session and httpstatus OK back.
After that he's able to call his role specific endpoint within the ui service. The auth verification works with the shared redis session.

**CODE:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//Security Routine for handling mobile login
public class RestSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);

        http.addFilterAt(new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

**QUESTION:**

Why is the return a 400 error and not staus ok whereas the login was successful?

Comment: Why do you need a custom filter if all you want to do is redirect after login? It also breaks other functions that happen in the `onSuccessFullAuthentication`. Also adding authorities like this won't work, it is pretty much useless what is happening here.

Comment: Even with not using the successhandler I get 404 error

Comment: I won't do a redirect. This was an old snipped that worked in aprevious example/test. In general I just want to authenticate without a form. Best thing would be just to call a url with my credentials in the header, execute the login and get a reponse with session and status back.

Comment: That is what basic authentication already does... You either get a 200 OK, or a 401/403. Why would you need to have more? The session details are in the cookie that represents the session or the header if you choose to use that with Spring Session. Feels like you are working around the things that should work and try to invent your own. Create something like a `/userinfo` endpoint which shows the current user, and you need to be authenticated to access it. Let them call that to do a login.